# Creating multi threads and increment counter with condition

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I am trying to write a function called thr_incrementer in C to variables are incremented by N tasks(N is defined by a constant). Each task is assigned an id identifier (between 0 and N-1) and they only increment a counter when

> id = counter % N

For now i have this but, `id = (counter % NTHREADS)` doesn't work at all.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define NTHREADS 10

void *thr_incrementer(void *);
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int counter =0;


void *thr_incrementer(void *arg){
    
    int id = 0;
    
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);

    for(id = 0; id <NTHREADS ; id++){

        if (id == (counter % NTHREADS)){
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    printf("ID: %d\n",id);
    
}


int main(){
    
    pthread_t thread[NTHREADS];
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thr_incrementer, NULL);
    }


    if(pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex) != 0){
        printf("Error destorying mutex.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Thread: %ln\n",thread);
 
}
```

Comment: `undefined reference to 'pthread_create' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`: add `-lpthread` to link with the lib

Comment: `Each task is assigned an id identifier` : there is nothing doing that in your code, *id* values 0..NTHREADS-1 whatever the thread

Comment: I was trying to create 10 threads and each threads there will be id number, not id of threads. At least what i understood from work. I also thought using pthread_self() but i am not sure the id asking here is the id of thread

Comment: the statement says the id is 0..N-1 so it is not *pthread_self*. Why are you not using *i* in *main* and give it through the arg received by *thr_incrementer* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For now i have this but, `id = (counter % NTHREADS)` [sic] doesn't work at all.

Of course, the test in your code is actually `id == (counter % NTHREADS)` (`==` is not the same as `=`).  And that test works just fine, but it's pointless in the code given.  Consider:

- `counter` initially takes the value 0

  > ```
  > int counter =0;
  > ```
- Each thread has its own *local* variable `id`, which initially takes value 0, and which each thread modifies as it runs.  This does not match the problem description's "Each task is assigned an id identifier", nor does there appear to be anything else in the code that matches that provision.
- each thread does substantially all its work, including all modifications to the global `counter` variable within a single critical region.  Therefore, no other threads' actions will be interleaved.
- each thread increments its `id` variable in a loop.  If it happens that `id == (counter % NTHREADS)` then it also increments `counter`.  In that event, that condition will be satisfied on the next iteration, too, because `id` and counter` each get incremented by one.
- furthermore, `id` starts at 0 in each thread, and `counter` starts at 0 for the whole program.  Therefore, the first thread will increment `counter` as many times as it increments `id` -- `NTHREADS` times overall.  `NTHREADS % NTHREADS` is 0, so the same thing happens again when each subsequent thread acquires the mutex.

Thus the problem is not that `id == (counter % NTHREADS)` doesn't work, but rather that, given your code, it is always true when evaluated.

My best guess is that you want each thread to increment `counter` once only, on its own turn.  To accomplish this, you need to

1. implement the specification that "Each task is assigned an id identifier" in a way that conveys the assigned identifier to each thread.  To give different data to different threads generally involves using the fourth argument to `pthread_create()`, which the thread function receives as its (only) argument.
2. use a condition variable together with your mutex to enable threads to suspend operation while waiting for their turn.  You can find numerous answers here on SO about how to do that properly.
3. When a thread's turn to increment the counter arrives, it performs just one increment, not multiple, and it does not modify its own assigned ID.

There are still plenty of details for you to work out.  I leave these as the exercise they are intended to be.